# Compilation error migrating from Spring 2 to Spring 5: incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.Class

Tags: java, spring, java-8

We are migrating from Spring 2.5.6 to Spring 5.3.29 and we are needing to upgrade some code parts like this:

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.util.buscador;

import aaa.bbb.ccc.dto.SBFormDto;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.dto.buscador.BusquedaDto;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("bDtoFactory")
public class BDtoFactoryImpl implements BDtoFactory {

    private static final String BL = "bl";
    private static final String BP = "bp";

    @Autowired
    BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public BusquedaDto crearBL(String textoLibre) {
        return (BusquedaDto) beanFactory.getBean(BL, new Object[] { textoLibre });
    }

    public BusquedaDto crearBP(SBFormDto formulario) {
        return (BusquedaDto) beanFactory.getBean(BP, new Object[] { formulario });
    }

}
```

I have been investigating about this and found this in the Spring Repository:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/10460

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/e137b10978ee183f861467353c4c92c00ca3702b#diff-94970c87189413d9d2065d13608a97ccf4fa045e79e6fdcf549a13b2d727a87c

```
// Old deprecated method    
Object getBean(String name, Object[] args) throws BeansException;

// New method
Object getBean(String name, Object... args) throws BeansException;
```

I don't understand why this getBean method doesn't work with an array. The compilation errors are:

```
[ERROR] BDtoFactoryImpl.java:[20,74] incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.Class

[ERROR] BDtoFactoryImpl.java:[24,78] incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.Class
```

Comment: should work since spring 2.5 . What is the current version? Have you checked the (decompiled) source of the BeanFactory you are calling?

Comment: Your research is off. The `Object[]` and `Object...` variants aren't "old, deprecated" and "new" - __They are the same method__, in java terms there is no signature difference between the two, and calls to the 'old' take work just as well, there is no need to recompile anything. It does not explain this error. You The 'new' code is from 2009; that is __not__ the code you are compiling against, or you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: Excuse me @Stultuske, I cannot know the exact implementation, because is a compilation error durin g "mvn clean install". I only know that the interface library is "spring-beans-5.3.29.jar".

Comment: @rzwitserloot you are right, it is not a new method is the same method with a declaration update, it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @IgnacioRafael I understand that, my point is that you need to figure out which version of spring is being used by that maven instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the key, as @Stultuske suggest, I have redirected my investigations to the Spring Version and I finally solve the problem at my first try: I have deleted all Spring Versions to force Maven download only the last one.

Problem solved, for any reason I don't know, it is possible that multiples Spring Version in my local repository were hindering the maven compilation.

Thank you very much!